# Get rid of lines in bootstrap dropdown navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to get rid of these lines separating the menu items? I've been looking under the .dropdown-menu class in the bootstrap css, but I can't find anything that will alter the lines.  [image]

Comment: Please provide some code or better, replicate the problem in a fiddle/plunker?

Comment: You might have added the divider between the navbar items.

Comment: Remove top & bottom border from li elements.

Answer (score 0):

the default nav bar drop down menu doesn't look like this
see an example : https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

it may be another css file you include in your project that cause this effect